# How to install gnupg-pkcs11-scd in RHEL 8.4?

Tags: rhel, package-management, smartcard

I am trying  to install `gnupg-pkcs11-scd` in rhel with `yum` but its not there in repo. Tries searching with `yum list *pkcs11*` but no luck. But it's present in Debian!

Am I searching it with wrong name or is there any alternative for RHEL?

Comment: Please try yum list  gnupg2.*     I think only 2.0 of gnupg is supported on Rhel8.

Comment: yum list gnupg2.* shows only installed gpg package named as gnupg2.x86_64

Comment: I don't have it installed,  but I can see it listed from a fedora repo.  I can't say if it will work though I've found that many Fedora packages will work on Rhel.   You can find the RPM at https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/g/